# Is Bida'h a major sin or minor sin?

Tags: sin, bidah

Haram = any activity prohibited in Islam which is against the moral values and principles.

Bida'h = a new practice that people say is a part of Islam, but in fact is not.

I know there are many kinds of Haram activities. I have studied the [major sins](http://www.themodernreligion.com/misc/hh/major_sins.htm) of Islam. But Bida'h is not listed. Yet Bida'h is a sin. Bida'h leads to shirk. And we know shirk is the biggest of all sins. So is Bida'h a major sin or minor sin?

Comment: I just want to bring to your attention that [major sins](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30111/what-are-the-major-sins-in-islam/30113#30113) are not only 70 as listed in the link you provided in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Bid'ah could be a major or a minor sin depending on **its category and the degree of seriousness**:

1. **Bid'ah that leads to Kufr (بدعة مُكفّرة)**. It is any Bid'ah that denies/rejects an obligation in Islam, or making up a new obligation in Islam, making things Halal or Haram while they are not, believing certain things about Allah (SWT) and His Messengers (PBUT), denying certain facts about Allah (SWT) or his Angels, Messenger (PBUT), Holy Books, etc..
2. **Bid'ah that does not lead to Kufr (بدعة غير مُكفّرة)**. (There are tons of this type of Bid'ah nowadays).

Not all innovations that lead to kufr are considered major sins. The way you differentiate between the ones that are considered major sins and the ones that are considered minor sins is whether the Bid'ah is against the basic teachings of Islam or not and its extent if it is against the basic teachings of Islam.

Allah knows best.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. Is it based on the teachings of any scholar or your understanding?

Comment: @0aslam0, if you search types of Bid'ah, you will find out that this is what the majority of scholars have agreed upon. This is not my own understanding.