# Is it a major sin?

Tags: halal-haram

Is it a major sin for one who touched or rubbed her own hip - but not genital area, so it is not masturbation - with bad thoughts in mind?

Comment: Again, your question is still difficult to comprehend. What are you actually trying to imply?. If you touch yourself with a lustful intent, then it's not permissible. And why do you keep saying it's not masturbation but with bad thoughts in mind??. If your thought/intent is bad then your action is also judged accordingly.

Comment: You say it's not permissible, but I just want to learn if it is major sin or not. I'm sorry, I have obsessive compulsive disorder and I want a specific answer, what did you mean by ^''not permissible?'' I said it's not masturbation because it had nothing to do with genital area or finger

Comment: What do you mean by "with bad thoughts in mind"?. What bad thoughts can there be when one is touching one's own body?. Can you elaborate on that bad thought?.

Comment: like sexual thoughts

Comment: Maybe this might help you in understanding what are major sins in Islam, https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30111/46502

Comment: If you read a question title saying "Is it a major sin?" would you really want to answer or do you feel you can answer the question? Please write meaningful question titles. Add all necessary information in your post and before all of this do some prior research and share it! One liner questions are mostly an evidence for no efforts done to solve the problem by yourself or one liner answers mostly show that one is not able to answer the question and explain the issue properly.

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. With regards to just touching your buttocks or any body part then there are no issues. However, if you touch them with those thoughts that creates enough sexual arousal in your body and you then ejaculate then that would not be permissible according to some scholars.

Regarding intention in it of itself there is no harm as seen from the hadith below:

‘Abdullah bin ‘Abbas (radhiAllahu anhu) reported that the Messenger of Allah (sallaAllahu alayhe wasallam) said that Allah, the Glorious, said: “Verily, Allah has ordered that the good and the bad deeds be written down. Then He explained it clearly how (to write): He who intends to do a good deed but he does not do it, then Allah records it for him as a full good deed, but if he carries out his intention, then Allah the Exalted, writes it down for him as from ten to seven hundred folds, and even more. But if he intends to do an evil act and has not done it, then Allah writes it down with Him as a full good deed, but if he intends it and has done it, Allah writes it down as one bad deed.” [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

Now if you are adding the rubbing your hip with the thoughts of sexual nature then you are crossing the bounds as that would be classified as masturbation and would be impermissible according to the majority of the scholars. If it is just rubbing and that's all then there is no issue.

**Recommendation**

Instead of rubbing your hips with those thoughts perhaps the girl can get married. If not then to start fasting. Another way to remove yourself from those situations / environments that can arouse those type of thoughts.

**Have a nice day!**